# How to redirect with parameters when clicked enter?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect, input

I've been wondering how to redirect to a certain site with the query parameters in the url.

```
<input id="query" name="query" placeholder="Search" type="input" >
```

I have tried using JavaScript code

```
<input id="query" name="query" placeholder="Search" type="input" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) submitForm()" >



<script>
  function submitForm() {
    var query = document.getElementById("query").value;
    window.location.href = "redirecturl?query=" + query;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
window.location.replace( ... )
```

instead of

```
window.location.href
```

like:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.key == "Enter") {
    const query = document.getElementById("query").value
    window.location.replace("https://google.com/search?q=" + query)
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="query">
```